# Problem with "row-fluid" in bootstrap, why my "divs" are skipping lines?

Tags: html, grid, row, col

For some reason, the 'Long Text' content under the 4th row under the "col-8" is being placed under the "col-4" instead of by its side. I've tried using the "span4" and "span8" code and didn't work.

````
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class = "col-12 titles">
                <h1>Global Warming is Real</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div>
                <div class = "col-12">
                    <img src="./pics/mainPic.jpg" alt="Responsive image" class = "img-fluid pics">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h2 class = "titles"> What are the causes? </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="./pics/burningFossil.jpg" alt="" class ="img-thumbnail rounded-circle pics" id = "pics-fossil">
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                Long Text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by adding the classes `float-left` and `float-right` to the rows, depending on which side you want them to be on

```html
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="col-4 float-left">
    <img src="./pics/burningFossil.jpg" alt="" class ="img-thumbnail rounded-circle pics" id = "pics-fossil">
  </div>
  <div class="col-8 float-right">
    Long Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it did fix this particulary problem. But now when I add new rows, it gets all messed up. I feel there's something wrong with the way I'm griding this. I just can't figure out what it is.